# TensorFlow installation in R in Windows 10

Tags: r, tensorflow, installation, anaconda

I'm trying to install keras and tensorflow for R.  However, I get a Warning message and an Error message.  I followed the instructions provided at https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/installation/.  I also downloaded Anaconda3 and updated `conda` to the latest version 4.8.5.  I am using the latest versions of R (Version 4.0.2) and RStudio (Version 1.3.1093) locally on a Windows 10 laptop.

I've also reviewed the relevant threads on Stack Overflow and followed their suggestions, including uninstalling and reinstalling R, RStudio, and Anaconda, as well as installing Python (Version 4.8.5).

1. Why am I getting a Warning message to update conda even though I already updated conda to the latest version?
2. Why does "installation complete" after running after running `install_tensorflow()` but I get "Error: Installation of TensorFlow not found." when I run `tf$constant("Hello")`?
3. How do I fix these issues?

```
> library(keras)
> library(tensorflow)
> install_tensorflow()
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done


==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 4.8.3
  latest version: 4.8.5

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda



# All requested packages already installed.

Requirement already up-to-date: tensorflow==2.2.0 in c:\users\owner\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (2.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: wheel>=0.26; python_version >= "3" in c:\users\owner\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==2.2.0) (0.34.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: wrapt>=1.11.1 in c:\users\owner\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==2.2.0) (1.12.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: gast==0.3.3 in c:\users\owner\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==2.2.0) (0.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: astunparse==1.6.3 in c:\users\owner\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==2.2.0) (1.6.3)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: h5py<2.11.0,>=2.10.0 in c:\users\owner\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==2.2.0) (2.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: protobuf>=3.8.0 in c:\users\owner\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==2.2.0) (3.13.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: keras-preprocessing>=1.1.0 in c:\users\owner\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==2.2.0) (1.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0 in c:\users\owner\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==2.2.0) (2.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: google-pasta>=0.1.8 in c:\users\owner\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==2.2.0) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: tensorflow-estimator<2.3.0,>=2.2.0 in c:\users\owner\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==2.2.0) (2.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: termcolor>=1.1.0 in c:\users\owner\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==2.2.0) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: opt-einsum>=2.3.2 in c:\users\owner\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==2.2.0) (3.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: absl-py>=0.7.0 in c:\users\owner\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==2.2.0) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: scipy==1.4.1; python_version >= "3" in c:\users\owner\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==2.2.0) (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: grpcio>=1.8.6 in c:\users\owner\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==2.2.0) (1.32.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: six>=1.12.0 in c:\users\owner\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==2.2.0) (1.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: numpy<2.0,>=1.16.0 in c:\users\owner\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow==2.2.0) (1.18.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: setuptools in c:\users\owner\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from protobuf>=3.8.0->tensorflow==2.2.0) (46.1.3.post20200330)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: requests<3,>=2.21.0 in c:\users\owner\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow==2.2.0) (2.24.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: google-auth<2,>=1.6.3 in c:\users\owner\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow==2.2.0) (1.21.3)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: tensorboard-plugin-wit>=1.6.0 in c:\users\owner\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow==2.2.0) (1.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1 in c:\users\owner\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow==2.2.0) (0.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: werkzeug>=0.11.15 in c:\users\owner\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow==2.2.0) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: markdown>=2.6.8 in c:\users\owner\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow==2.2.0) (3.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: chardet<4,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\owner\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow==2.2.0) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\owner\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow==2.2.0) (2020.6.20)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: idna<3,>=2.5 in c:\users\owner\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow==2.2.0) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\owner\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.21.0->tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow==2.2.0) (1.25.10)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: cachetools<5.0,>=2.0.0 in c:\users\owner\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow==2.2.0) (4.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1 in c:\users\owner\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow==2.2.0) (0.2.8)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: rsa<5,>=3.1.4; python_version >= "3.5" in c:\users\owner\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow==2.2.0) (4.6)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0 in c:\users\owner\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1->tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow==2.2.0) (1.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: importlib-metadata; python_version < "3.8" in c:\users\owner\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from markdown>=2.6.8->tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow==2.2.0) (2.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pyasn1<0.5.0,>=0.4.6 in c:\users\owner\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1->google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow==2.2.0) (0.4.8)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: oauthlib>=3.0.0 in c:\users\owner\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0->google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1->tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow==2.2.0) (3.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: zipp>=0.5 in c:\users\owner\appdata\local\r-mini~1\envs\r-reti~1\lib\site-packages (from importlib-metadata; python_version < "3.8"->markdown>=2.6.8->tensorboard<2.3.0,>=2.2.0->tensorflow==2.2.0) (3.2.0)

Installation complete.


Restarting R session...

> tf$constant("Hello")
Error: Installation of TensorFlow not found.

Python environments searched for 'tensorflow' package:
 C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\r-miniconda\envs\r-reticulate\python.exe

You can install TensorFlow using the install_tensorflow() function.
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
[1] tensorflow_2.2.0 keras_2.3.0.0   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.5       lattice_0.20-41  fansi_0.4.1     
 [4] zeallot_0.1.0    crayon_1.3.4     assertthat_0.2.1
 [7] rappdirs_0.3.1   grid_4.0.2       R6_2.4.1        
[10] jsonlite_1.7.1   magrittr_1.5     tfruns_1.4      
[13] rlang_0.4.7      cli_2.0.2        rstudioapi_0.11 
[16] whisker_0.4      Matrix_1.2-18    reticulate_1.16 
[19] generics_0.0.2   tools_4.0.2      glue_1.4.2      
[22] yaml_2.2.1       compiler_4.0.2   base64enc_0.1-3
```

Comment: Have you tried updating conda? `conda update -n base -c defaults conda`

Comment: @mhovd As mentioned, "I also downloaded Anaconda3 and updated conda to the latest version 4.8.5."  I did so using the Navigator, rather than command line, but that shouldn't matter

Comment: @IRTFM  In the third line of code, you will see that I executed "install_tensorflow()" .  The output is, among others, "Installation complete."